# migration Rollback error class not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Trying to Rollback but its giving me error that class'task' not found. Can someone please tell me why I am getting that error,
I also tried to remove the schema drop line but still its giving the same error

[image: trying to rollback but its giving me error class'Tasks' not found]

Comment: try to run composer dump-autoload

Comment: thanks for the help, it worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your command line run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```